# Flutter still loading network image even though i have a null check

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

In my flutter app I am storing the URLs from firebase storage inside Firestore. I am expecting there to be null URL's as it is dependent on the user uploading images. In my code I am checking for null values, but for some reason the code still tries to load the null values. How do I correctly prevent flutter from loading the null values in network image. My code for the load is as follows:

```
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 150,

  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: photoList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

        print(photoList[index]);

      return photoList[index] != null ? Image.network(photoList[index]) : Container(height:400,child: Text('No Images to Display'));
        
      }
  ),
),
```

Debug give the following for the print above when there is no image:

```
I/flutter (27038): url - null
```

When there is a image then there is a proper URL and the image loads without any issue.

So not quite sure why Flutter is still trying to load the null even though in that case of null I would like a text box instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the value of `photoList[index]` is not consistent. As it prints "url - null" when it's expected to contain a null value and when it's not null, it contains an actual url that loads an image.

You can the either of the following:

- Ensure your null images are actually null instead of "url - null" and the null check will work.
- Use the [errorBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/errorBuilder.html) property of the [Image.network](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) widget to display your error widgets like this:

  ```dart
  Image.network(photoList[index],
    errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
      return Container(height:400,child: Text('No Images to Display'));
    }
  )
  ```

Comment: Thanks . The URL's were null, but for some reason the logical check just didn't work. I have tested the errorBuilder and this seems to work perfectly. You were also correct in that the null is passed as string even though i have written it to firestore as a null. never thought to do the check as  'null'. thanks so much for pointing that out.

Comment: Okay, great to know it's worked. Well, ideally the null value should be actually `null` not a string "null". You should double-check the write operation. Check out the supported data type for Firestore here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types.

Answer (score 2):

What type of data stores in `photoList`? If `String` there is a chance "null" value is actually a string but not `null`.

Comment: apologies. i updated the `print` statement while writing this to update the output. the print statement in my current code is  `print('url - ${photoList[index]}');`